# Laravel function return me just NULL

Tags: php, laravel, api, response

I need to connect to an API to claim a voucher. At API doc I see:

```
POST /api/v1/vouchers/{voucherId}/claim

{
    "Participant": {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "James,
        "Telephone": "08456 127 127",
        "EmailAddress": "tim@asdasd.net",
        "PostCode": "ASD 9HX",
        "HouseNameNumber": "2",
        "Street": "Bridge Road2",
        "Locality": "LONDON",
        "Town": "Aylesbury",
        "County": "Bucks"
    },
    "ExperienceDate": "2017-10-01T00:00:00"
}
```

Based on this I write my function using Laravel framework:

```
public function testclaim()
    {

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
$headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'];
try {
$res = $client->post('https://api.example.com/api/v1/vouchers/244775_2-H8SC/claim', [
    'headers'=>$headers,
     'auth' => [
        'JAMES-JJ', 'ajhsdajsdhaj32423'
    ],
    'json' => [
    'Participant' => [
        "FirstName"=> "asdasd",
        "LastName"=> "asdasd",
        "Telephone"=> "08456 127 127",
        "EmailAddress"=> "tim@asdasd.net",
        "PostCode"=> "HP18 9HX",
        "HouseNameNumber"=> "1",
        "Street"=> "Bridge Road",
        "Locality"=> "Ickford",
        "Town"=> "Aylesbury",
        "County"=> "Bucks"
    ],
    'ExperienceDate' => '2017-11-01T00:00:00'
]
            ]);
$res = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);

    return response()->json(['data' => $res]);

//dd($res);
}
catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $result =  json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

    return response()->json(['data' => $result]);

    }

    }
```

Now when I run this function I just get:

```
{"data":null}
```

ANybody see what is wrong in my code?
How to solve this issue?

I also try without header to send a request but again I get the same response from API.

Comment: So do a debug. You know what is it? What is the value of `$res`? Before `json_decode`, after `json_decode`.

Comment: What's the ouput of `$res`?

Comment: DO a var_dump() or dd() of res to see if the API returned something, if it has maybe you're just returning the wrong stuff.

Comment: when I write dd($res) i just get NULL

Comment: when I write var_dump I get: object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)#215 (6) { ["reasonPhrase":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> string(7) "Created" ["statusCode":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> int(201) ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Respo....

Comment: dd($res) before json_decode return me this https://imgur.com/a/EMDd7

Comment: Also, when I change 'json' to form_param I get: {"data":{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"claim":["An error has occurred."]}}}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need getContents() if you want to convert the body to an Array.